# Stream ceated by fs.createReadStream does not write into array although wrapped into a promise

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, csv, fs

I am reading a stream from a csv file and want to push certain rows into an array. Unfortunately the stream is being closed before the writing into the array is finished. I will share my code here:

```
const parseFromCSVFile = (filename: string, start: number, end: number)=> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let jsonArray: any = []
    const readingStream = fs.createReadStream(`${filepath}/${filename}.csv`, {start, end})
        readingStream.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log("error", error);
        })
    
        .pipe(csv({ separator: ',' }))
        .on('data', (line) => {
            
            readingStream.pause()
            jsonArray.push(line)
            readingStream.resume()
                
        })
    
        .on('end', () => {
            resolve(jsonArray)
            
        })
        .on("error", () => {
            reject()
        })
    })
}

parseFromCSVFile("test", 0 , 10000).then((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.length);
    
    
})
```

The variable `res` should have the length 10000 but unfortunately it has the length 53. If I decrease `end` even further the function returns an empty array. If anyone can help me with this or would recommend another library or approach for this, I would be very grateful! I have searched through a lot of Stackoverflow Q&As for this!

Comment: `.pipe(csv({ separator: ',' }))` Please provide more information about this `csv` function you're using. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it differently. Since the `start` and `end` variable do not refer to the lines in the file in this case but to bytes I needed to remove them since they caused the data to be stripped down to 53 objects or 10000 bytes. My final solution looks like this:

```
export const parseFromCSVFile = (filename: string, start: number, end: number)=> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let jsonArray: any = []
    let count = 0
    const readingStream = fs.createReadStream(`${tempFilePath}/${filename}`)
        readingStream.on('error', (error) => {
            reject({message: error.message})
        })
        .pipe(csv({ separator: ',' }))
        .on('data', (line) => {
            count >= start && count <= end && jsonArray.push(line)
            if(count > end ){
                resolve(jsonArray)
                readingStream.close() 
        }
                
        count += 1
        })

        .on('end', () => {
            resolve(jsonArray)
            readingStream.close()
            
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
            reject({message: error.message})
        })
    })
}
```